# error number 2003 while re-installing MySQL server instance configuration 5.5

Tags: mysql

I unistalled `mysql 5.5` from my system. Now when i am re-installing it is giving me following error:

```
The security settings could not be applied.
Error number 2003
can't connect to localhost 10061.
```

In the description of this error it is mentioned that if you are re-installing `mysql` then you must provide your old password, so, when i enter the old password(as i remember) in the `mysql` command line which get installed after above error,window get closed with a beep sound showing some error.

Please suggest what should i do?

Comment: You'll probably have to grant 'localhost' privileges to on the table to the user. See the 'GRANT' syntax documentation. Here's an example (from some C source).

"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON %s.* TO '%s'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '%s'";

Comment: where should i write these code lines?